# ImageIO.read(inStream) return null(tried many ways but still return null)

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to insert a image to my database via jsp, I use InputStream and BufferedImage to insert this image in my database. However, the ImageIO.read(inStream) keep return to null after I tried a few way in stackoverflow.
here is my code:

```
DiskFileUpload diskFileUpload = new DiskFileUpload();
            List files = diskFileUpload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator i = files.iterator();
            FileItem file = null;
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                file=(FileItem)i.next();
                if(file!=null){
                    InputStream inStream=file.getInputStream();
                    out.println(inStream);
                    BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(inStream);
                    out.println(image);
```

as you see, when I print inStream, it is java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@7bb55b75 but when I print image it is null.

Any advice will be nice, thank you